# Error; Variable Referenced Before Assignment

Tags: python

I'm getting an `Error; Variable Referenced Before Assignment` for myhp.
At the starting of my .py file, I have "myhp = 20" though.

What do I do to get this working?

```
def fightmode(name, hp, dmg, gold):
    print '\n\n\nYou are in a fight with %s' %name
    print '%s has %sHP' %(name, hp)
    while myhp > 0 and hp > 0:
        print '\n\t1. Attack \n\t2. Guard \n\t3. Run away.'
        opt1= ''
        allowed = ["1", "2", "3"]
        while opt1 not in allowed:
            opt1 = raw_input("\nWhat will you do? ")
            if opt1 == "1":
                hp = hp - mydmg
                print "You have inflicted %d damage on %s. %s's HP is %s" %(mydmg, name, name, hp)
            if opt1 == "2":
                myhp = myhp+5
                print "You are now guarding yourself. Your HP is now %d" %myhp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert `global myhp` at the beginning of the function. If you assign to the variable in the function, Python treats it as local unless you declare it as global.

Comment: I think that did it. But now I'm receiving this error. "can only concatenate list (not int) to list" for my line myhp = myhp + 5

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you have myhp = 20. myhp is a local here, so it has not been assigned. If you want to use the global, put `global myhp` at the beginning of your function.

Comment: this is just a function, I have declared myhp outside of this function.

and now I'd like to use that as a local im guessing